# Error: Could not find or load main class net.sourceforge.cobertura.merge.Main

Tags: java, classpath, cobertura

I am getting this strange error while excuting following commands..

```
 cobertura-merge.bat --auxClasspath ./cobertura-2.0.3.jar --datafile cobertura.ser cobertura1.ser cobertura2.ser

 cobertura-merge.bat --auxClasspath . --datafile cobertura.ser cobertura1.ser cobertura2.ser
```

**Error -** 
Error: Could not find or load main class net.sourceforge.cobertura.merge.Main

PS -

1. I have JAVE HOME set.
2. Java bin dir is added to PATH.
3. CLASSPATH is defined with - %CLASSPATH%;.;.
4. I have added cobertura-2.0.3.jar in jdk lib and jre lib directory.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same problem.  To fix this, you will need to **edit the cobertura-merge.bat** in a text editor.  The last line looks something like this:

```
java -cp "%COBERTURA_HOME%cobertura.jar;%COBERTURA_HOME%lib\asm-3.3.1.jar;.....
```

The jar file names in this command most likely do not match the jar file names in your cobertura_home\lib.

Example:
In the command above, from the batch file, it references 'cobertura.jar'
If you look in the lib folder, the actual name of the file is 'cobertura-2.0.3.jar

The same goes for the other jar files.  So you will have to change the bat file, or the file names, to make them match.